# Trigger Events - Shopify and BOLD Options 2

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, shopify

I'm creating a multiple step form on a Shopify product page using Javascript. To add more options to the product I am using BOLD Options 2 Shopify app. Each step in the form sets the Shopify variants and BOLD Options of the product with an onclick event.

```
 function selectFormElement(id, valueToSelect){ 
    var theBox = document.getElementById(id);
    for (var i = 0; i < theBox.options.length; i++) {
      if (theBox.options[i].value == valueToSelect) {
          theBox.options[i].selected = true;
          return;
        }
      }}
```

This sets the value of the HTML but all the variants and options revert to their defaults when added to the cart. After researching the problem I found that you have to trigger an “option_changed” event for the BOLD Options app to recognize the change. I found a list of BOLD Option events https://github.com/bold-commerce/Product-Options/wiki/Events. Using this as a reference, I still have not been able to get the event to trigger.

```
BOLD.options.app.emit('option_changed', { id: valueToSelect });
```

Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you not call Bold. They have 100 people standing by with nothing better to do than help out their clients.

Comment: I did. They said, " we're not able to help you with this as the app isn't capable of this out of the box."

Comment: Sounds like a cop-out...

Comment: Most likely. Can it not trigger its own event out of the box?. Maybe they have a good reason for their response. Whatever it might be Ill just keep working toward a solution.